# Changing .click(function() { of an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a group of clickable images which designate specific services offered. When a user clicks an image the form associated with that service slides into the frame. All forms are multi-part and subsequent parts are accessed via a clickable div (like a 'CONTINUE' button). All forms begin with 'Step1' and subsequent parts vary depending on the service selected.

What I am trying to do is change the `.click (function()` of the 'CONTINUE button' based on the service selected.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="form-holder">
<form id="inquiry" action="" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="select">
<p>Please select a service from the options below:</p>

<div id="service1"><img class="product_img" src="" alt=" " />
<h1 style="margin-top: 0px">SERVICE ONE</h1></div>

<div id="service2"><img class="product_img" src="" alt="" />
<h1>SERVICE TWO</h1></div>

</div><!--End Select-->

<div id="step1">

<fieldset id="field1">
<legend>Contact Information</legend>

<div class="inline">
<div> Company Name:<br />
<input name="Company Name" size="20" type="text" /></div>

<div>Contact Person: <br />
<input name="Contact Person" size="20" type="text" /></div>

<div> Title/Affiliation: <br />
<input name="Affiliation" size="20" type="text" /></div></div>

</fieldset>

<div id="next1" class="next1">CONTINUE</div>

</div><!--End Step1-->



<div id="step2">

<fieldset>
<legend>Company Information</legend>

<div class="inline2">
<div> Products/Services:<br />
<textarea id="inline" name="Products"></textarea></div>

<div> Affiliations/Licensing: <br />
<textarea id="inline" name="Licenses"></textarea></div></div>

</fieldset>

<div class="next2">CONTINUE</div>

</div><!--End Step2-->



<div id="step3">

<fieldset>
<legend>Design Goals</legend>

<div class="inline2">
<div>
<textarea id="inline" name="Examples"></textarea></div>
<div>
<textarea id="inline" name="Features"></textarea></div></div>

<div>Additional Information :<br />
<textarea id="full" name="Comments"></textarea></div>

</fieldset>

<input id="send" type="submit" value="Sumit Query"><input type="reset" value="Clear" style="margin-left: 490px" />

</div><!--End Step3-->

</form>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#service1").click(function() {
$(".select").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
$("#step1").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
});
});


$(document).ready(function() {
$(".next1").click(function() {
$("#step1").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
$("#step2").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#service2").click(function() {
$(".select").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
$("#step1").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
$("#next1").addClass('next2').removeClass('next1');
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".next2").click(function() {
$("#step1").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
$("#step3").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
});
});
```

The goal is to change the class of `"#next1"` when `"#service2"` is selected so it will animate #step3 of the form rather than `"#step2"`.

Is this possible?

I'm fairly new to jQuery and can use all the help I can get. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

M.J.

Comment: It also helps to specify what roadblock you've run into so that others don't have to read through all that code and play whack the mole.

Comment: First off you can include all of your code in a single `$(document).ready(function() {...});` block

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bind()` and `unbind()` if you want to change the click event to nothing or something else.

```
// bind click
$('#myelement').bind('click', function() { 
   // do work
});

// unbind click
$('#myelement').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe for your suggestion. I resolved the issue using the .live() method suggested by Jeff Wilbert, although after looking at his demo page, it appears as though the .bind() method would work as well. Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should look into...

First of all everything you write should be within:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

You have four separate sections here, but they should all be within the ready function.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do but I would consider created two different forms and adding them to two separate divs. 
If a user clicks option one fade the appropriate form in.

```
 $("#service1").click(function() {
    $("#service1form").fadeIn();
 });
```

Then you can use something like this for your continue button:

```
 $("#service1form .continue").click(function(){...
```

or

```
 $('#service1form .step2").click(function(){....
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank-you for pointing out the error in my syntax, James. I'm a little 'green' with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the class of an element, jQuery doesn't change the events that were bound to it when you used `.bind()` or a shorthand event method like `.click()` because jQuery sets those event handlers once when you called those methods and doesn't recognize that you changed an elements class to something else you've defined event handlers and to now use those instead unless you use `.live()`.

**Description of .bind()**:
"Attach a handler to an event for the elements."

To fix this use the `.live()` method.

**Description of .live()**:
"*Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.*"

The keyword there to your solution is "*the future*".  By changing the elements class you want it then use the bound events you set for that class and not the events you set on page load for the class it originally had, this will allow that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#service1").click(function() {
        $(".select").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
        $("#step1").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
    });

    $("#service2").click(function() {
        $(".select").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
        $("#step1").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
        $("#next1").addClass('next2').removeClass('next1');
    });

    $(".next1").live('click', function() {
        $("#step1").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
        $("#step2").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
    });

    $(".next2").live('click', function() {
        $("#step1").animate({width:"0%"}, 1000);
        $("#step3").animate({width:"77%"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Here is a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgQ5v/) showcasing both `.bind()` and `.live()` in action.

Comment: Your suggestion works to a degree Jeff. The problem now is both events are being triggered when .next2 is clicked. I appreciate the prompt response and I will look at the demo you recommended. Maybe that will shed some additional light on my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, they don't both get called in the example, the only way to call both event handles is if the element has both classes, i.e. if you add `$("#next1").addClass('next2');` and not  removing next1 OR you have both a `.bind() / .click()` and `.live()` method on your element, in which case live is to replace bind not be set with it.

Comment: I got it Jeff! Thank-you for your help! You ROCK!

Comment: The problem was with my poor syntax. Just as James Johnson pointed out. I was wrongly separating each function with the $(document).ready declaration. It is now working as expected. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working; don't forget to mark the answer most helpful and correct to your questions.  You'll be more likely to get more answers to future questions you have if you maintain your marked answer(s)/question ratio.